# Data Provider for SAP BW

Tags: database, ssis, etl, ssas, sap-bw

I am trying to create SSIS package for loading the data from SAP BW to SQL Server. But after read through many books people are saying we need Data Provider to load the data from SAP BW to SQL Server.

Can someone suggest me where can I get these Data Providers for SSIS?

Answer (score 1):

A good article on SSIS with SAP Connectors directly from Microsoft:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/ssis-with-sap-connectors.aspx

Generally useful page, you can find a SAP connection manager for download here: http://ssisctc.codeplex.com/

You should probably bookmark the second link as it has a wide range of SSIS tools that will definitely be useful for you.